# Disk encryption utility does not start after emergency reboot during upgrade

Tags: linux, boot, arch-linux, luks, umount

I have Arch Linux and disk encryption installed. During an update, the system hung and I used a keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>), which was a big mistake on my part. A shutdown occurred during the update process and I could not start the system anymore.

[image]

Comment: Do what is your question?  We really need more info to help. From your screenshot the problem is either LUKS is not mounting/running or the rest is an issue with LVM. Are you running in normal or some mind of rescue mode? Have you tried manually rebuilding this? Is your goal to recover data or fix your system?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the "Warning: …" line, your initramfs image is corrupted (some steps failed during its generation), and is unable to load the drivers (kernel modules) required for accessing your system disk. Whether encrypted or not, the disk is entirely invisible to the OS until drivers are loaded.

Your options:

- Try the `initramfs-linux-fallback.img` initramfs image. Because both images are generated separately, there's a chance for at least one of them working well. (Press <kbd>e</kbd> in your boot menu and see if your boot manager lets you edit the initramfs path and other parameters.)
- Use a live CD/USB to boot the system, manually unlock the root partition using `cryptsetup open`, do the [mount/chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chroot#Using_arch-chroot) dance, and run `mkinitcpio -P` inside the chroot in order to rebuild the initramfs.

  (Or perhaps just reinstall the kernel package while you're at it, in case more files are corrupted than just the initramfs. `pacman -S linux` will do that and trigger an initramfs rebuild anyway.)